# Ninject: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, ioc-container, ninject

I am using Ninject 2 with Asp.Net Mvc 2.0 (.Net 4 and IIS 6.0). My Global.asax.cs looks like this.

```
  public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}.aspx/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var modules = new INinjectModule[]
                                {
                                    new ControllerModule(),
                                    new Log4NetModule()
                                };

            return new StandardKernel(modules);
        }
    }
```

And the **ControllerModule** looks like this.

```
   public class ControllerModule : NinjectModule
      {
          public override void Load()
          {
              Bind<HomeController>().ToSelf();
              Bind<ProductController>().ToSelf();
              Bind<CustomerController>().ToSelf();
              ..........
              ..........
          }
    }
```

But on the live Server I can see following **intermittent** error in **Elmah**. Am I missing something here..

```
Ninject: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Ninject.Activation.Strategies.PropertyInjectionStrategy.Activate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference)
   at Ninject.Activation.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Activate>b__0(IActivationStrategy s)
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action)
   at Ninject.Activation.Pipeline.Activate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7(IContext context)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Create>b__1(ITarget target)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7(IContext context)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**Update :**  This issue is resolved when I took the latest Ninject for .Net 4 from the git hub.

Comment: Please complain to MS, the IIS memory is completely useless, and fact that you need to use farming to utilize more than 1GB physical memory is utter BS.

Comment: @leppie: But the application was working fine before I introduced Ninject.

Comment: @Amitabh: You maybe have been close to the limits already. Investigate physical memory usage with and without Ninject. I am not ruling out a Ninject bug, however.

Comment: @leppie: It can be an IIS limit. However do you think the way I have used the Ninject in Asp.Net Mvc 2 is correct?

Comment: Have you any bindings in RequestScope?

Comment: @Remo: I have bindings in the RequestScope.

Comment: Ah I think I missed the update. The latest verion of Ninject does a faster release of InRequestScope. So I think there were to many unreleased InRequestScope instances.